# HOWTO configure hibernate.cfg.xml, struts.xml, MessageResources.properties based on values in build.properties

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, build, struts2

For a Struts2 project that is compiled via ant what are the best practices or approach for modifying variables in hibernate.cfg.xml (e.g. hibernate.connection.url), struts.xml (e.g. struts.devMode), MessageResources.properties (e.g. appName?) etc. using ant build tools?

I have a build.properties (& local.build.properties setup in different server instances like qa, staging etc.) but I dont know if there is a uniform approach to override/overwrite values in the various project config files like hibernate.cfg.xml etc using the build tool.

I am looking, preferably, for a uniform solution which will work on all config files. But if not, then specifci approaches for specific config files is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Weel for your case, my honest suggestion is to move to the Maven.

1. In Maven you can define `<profiles/>` (a.k.a testing.staging,live etc) which allow you to configure settings for different environments.All you need to specify Maven about the environment for which you want the things to move and Maven is capable enough to take care of this.Though this can be done with Ant also but i believe that Maven provides more flexibility.
2. You have the option to use resource filtering in Maven.

I am not very familiar with Ant, but believe you can have 2 different copies of settings may be at two different locations or with two different names and you can pass the name at build execution time.

Still i will go with Maven based on its flexibility and ease of use.

Comment: This is good info. But my question is specifically about how to change the values of configs like hibernate.cfg.xml at build time. Be it ant or maven.

Comment: @Chantz: with maven i already said use profiles and all you need to set the profile flag like production/testing and it will automaticaly pick the respected setting. refer to this http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html and http://www.malethan.com/article/production_cfg_maven_profiles.html, hope they might help you